# How to split column in Spark Dataframe to multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my case how to split a column contain StringType with  a format '1-1235.0 2-1248.0 3-7895.2' to  another column with  ArrayType contains ['1','2','3']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is relatively simple with UDF:

```
val df = Seq("1-1235.0 2-1248.0 3-7895.2").toDF("input")

val extractFirst = udf((s: String) => s.split(" ").map(_.split('-')(0).toInt))

df.withColumn("newCol", extractFirst($"input"))
  .show()
```

gives

```
+--------------------+---------+
|               input|   newCol|
+--------------------+---------+
|1-1235.0 2-1248.0...|[1, 2, 3]|
+--------------------+---------+
```

I could not find an easy soluton with spark internals (other than using `split` in combination with `explode` etc and then re-aggregating)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string to an array using `split` function and then you can transform the array using Higher Order Function `TRANSFORM` (it is available since Sark 2.4) together with `substring_index`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{split, expr}

val df = Seq("1-1235.0 2-1248.0 3-7895.2").toDF("stringCol")

df.withColumn("array", split($"stringCol", " "))
  .withColumn("result", expr("TRANSFORM(array, x -> substring_index(x, '-', 1))"))
```

Notice that this is native approach, no UDF applied.

Comment: Incorrect? What if val df = Seq("1-1235.0 55-1248.0 3-7895.2").toDF("stringCol"), e.g. value greater than 9?

Comment: @thebluephantom Thanks for pointing out more digit values. I edited the answer by replacing substring to substring_index.